# c# best way to ping lot of hosts

Tags: c#, ping

I tried to run CMD and got ping info from there:

```
    ProcessStartInfo cmdStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    cmdStartInfo.FileName = @"cmd";
    cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    cmdStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    cmdStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    Process cmd = new Process();
    cmd.StartInfo = cmdStartInfo;
    cmd.ErrorDataReceived += DataReceived;
    cmd.OutputDataReceived += DataReceived;
    cmd.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    cmd.Start();
    cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
    cmd.BeginErrorReadLine();

    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("ping www.bing.com");
    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
    cmd.WaitForExit();
```

Is exist some better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly make sure that you are really in need of opening a shell to process the commands. In your example it would be simpler just to run `ping` directly, for example,

```
ProcessStartInfo cmdStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "ping",
    Arguments = "www.bing.com",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};

Process proc = Process.Start(cmdStartInfo);
string reply = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Where `ReadToEnd` will wait until the process is finished before returning, giving you the whole output of the ping. `ReadToEnd` would also work for your example though instead of the `Sleep`.

I assume it's just a contrived example but if not, you don't need to use ping like this - .net provides the `ping` class which is easier to work with. For example.

```
private static void Ping(string address = "bing.com", int iterations = 4)
{
    Ping ping = new Ping();
    var hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(address);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
    new Random().NextBytes(buffer);

    Console.WriteLine("Pinging {0} [{1}] with {2} bytes of data:", hostEntry.HostName, hostEntry.AddressList[0], buffer.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        PingReply reply = ping.Send(address, 1000, buffer);    
        Console.WriteLine("Reply from {0}: bytes={1}, time={2}ms, TTL={3}", reply.Address, reply.Buffer.Length, reply.RoundtripTime, reply.Options.Ttl);
    }
}
```

EDIT: to avoid hanging you could write it like this instead.

```
static void Main()
{
    Task<string> pingReply = RunCommand("ping", "bing.com");

    Console.WriteLine("I am waiting for ping to complete and could be doing something useful");

    pingReply.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine(pingReply.Result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static Task<string> RunCommand(string command, string args)
{
    ProcessStartInfo cmdStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = command,
        Arguments = args,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };

    Process proc = Process.Start(cmdStartInfo);        
    Task<string> readCommand = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();

    return readCommand;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but in this case ping is just the command for testing. Generally, here will be used another commands in future.